# Difference between $R/P$ and $R_P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $P$ be a prime ideal.

Consider the quotient Ring $R/P$ and localization $R_P$, in the [Borcherd's lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iB_-13reIA&pp=ygUYcGFyYWZhY3RvcmlhbCBsb2NhbCByaW5n), he said $R/P$ making $P$ minimal, but $R_P$ making $P$ maximal.

Can someone explain this to me in more detail?

Comment: $R_P$ has a unique maximal ideal, namely $P$. On the other hand, in $R/P$, $P$ is the zero coset. Take $R=\Bbb Z$ and $P=(2)$ to see this explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $R/P$, $P$ has been shrunk to a single element (the coset $0+P$) so $P/P=\{0+P\}$ is contained in all proper ideals of the quotient and can't get any smaller.

On the other hand, in $R_P$, things outside of $P$ have been converted to units, so the image of $P$ in the localization is the unique maximal ideal, containing all other proper ideals of the localization.

Comment: It would be neat if there was a "colocalization" construction that makes a chosen ideal minimal in a new ring, but I'm not aware if that exists...